# Docker for mac on machine that previously had boot2docker installed complains about TLS configuration

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I took an older macbook back in use. It previously had boot2docker installed when the native docker for mac didn't exist yet. That might be the root cause of my issue.

I've installed the new docker for mac but when I run docker-compose I've got the following error:

```
docker.errors.TLSParameterError: Path to a certificate and key files must be provided through the client_config param. TLS configurations should map the Docker CLI client configurations. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/https/ for API details.
```

I don't want to install a docker machine with virtual box or anything. I just want to run it natively like a fresh docker for mac installation. All the solutions I've found so far require me to use a docker-machine.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by unsetting all legacy docker machine environment variables so that it uses the correct docker commands

```
unset ${!DOCKER_*}
```

I've found the solution on the docker troubleshooting page over [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/#workarounds-for-common-problems).